# In Apple's file system programming, is there a way to do a combination of operations atomically?

Tags: cocoa

In Apple's file system programming, is there a way to do a combination of operations atomically? For example, is there a way to write two files atomically? There is a method of NSData - writeToURL:atomically:, which can write a file atomically. But it doesn't fit my need, since it can only handle a file atomically.

Comment: For what I know, there is no *primitive* operations to do a combination of operations atomically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that there is nothing on the higher level APIs, but there might be something at the Unix level, but probably not.

OS X and (I think iOS) just has a normal, non-transactional file system and if you want to guarantee atomicity you will probably have to code itself.

Even the atomic operation that you mention is simply a series of non-atomic operations with fall-backs, e.g. write to a temp file, if successful swap with target file (an atomic operation because it just change file pointers) and delete temp file.